# What body is the US Department of Homeland Security (DHS) accountable to for aviation security functions?

Tags: us-federal-government, dhs

The [United States House Transportation Subcommittee](https://transportation.house.gov/about/jurisdiction-and-rules) includes:

- transportation safety (**except** automobile safety and **transportation security functions of the Department of Homeland Security**)

Which bodies of the US government provide oversight of DHS Aviation Security functions?

Answer (score 10):

The Department of Homeland Security is a cabinet-level arm of the Executive Branch. The Sec'y of Homeland Security directly "runs" that branch, and serves at the pleasure of the President of the United States. There is a [House committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_Homeland_Security) on Homeland Security which conducts "oversight" and handles legislation related to security. There is likewise a [Senate committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_Committee_on_Homeland_Security_and_Governmental_Affairs). [This](https://www.dhs.gov/aviation-security) is the DHS page on aviation security; and [this is a house report](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-report/115th-congress/house-report/226/1) on TSA oversight, connected to [this bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/1351/text) which did not become law, but is on the topic as an example of what legislative oversight would mean.

Comment: In particular, the House Homeland Security committee has a [Subcommittee on Transportation and Maritime Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Homeland_Security_Subcommittee_on_Transportation_and_Maritime_Security).